# Calling properties in functions in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a very simple question about properties access in Javascript inside functions. Should be the easiest thing ever, but I cant realize why this doesn't work:

I have an object:

```
var myObj = {
    first: "First text",
    second: "Second text",
    third: "Third text"
};
```

And I want to call the first property:

```
console.log(myObj.first); // First text
```

Everything ok. But the I want to call this property from a function, and also assign a new property `"Fourth"` with a new value `"Fourth text"`:

```
function myFunction(myObj){
    console.log(this.first); // [object Object] undefined
    this.fourth = "Fourth text";
}
myFunction(myObj); 
console.log(myObj.fourth); // undefined
```

As you can see, the last two calls result in undefined. And I don't understand why! Any help will be very appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

You pass your `myObj` to your function but have used as `this`. Use the parameter of the `function`: `myObj.first` instead of `this.first`.

```js
var myObj = {
    first: "First text",
    second: "Second text",
    third: "Third text"
};

function myFunction(myObj){
    console.log(myObj.first);
    myObj.fourth = "Fourth text";
}

myFunction(myObj); 
console.log(myObj.fourth);
```

Or if you want to access with `this`, you need to bind the context to your `myObj` with: example `call` and pass your object as the first argument. Now `this` in your function will refer to the passed object.

```js
var myObj = {
        first: "First text",
        second: "Second text",
        third: "Third text"
    };

function myFunction(){
    console.log(this.first);
    this.fourth = "Fourth text";
}

myFunction.call(myObj); 
console.log(myObj.fourth);
```

Comment: Yes, I forgot that the function is not related with the object, and I should relate it. But I have another problem: my results in the Google Chrome console are different from yours. For example, if I run any of your solutions, I get `undefined undefined` and `undefined`…

Comment: Be attentive. Something wrong you have written in the Chrome. Look your code again, it can't be undefined

Comment: Yes, the problem is that I have myFunction defined in several places. In some way it was mixed with something; the solution is to asign a variable to the function: `var myFunction = function(){…}`

Comment: try to run this code in a new tab/window on google chrome and you will had expected results. when you will use it in your code make sure that you have not duplicates in your functions names

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the object.

```
myObj.first
^^^^^
```

```js
function myFunction(myObj){
    console.log(myObj.first);
    myObj.fourth = "Fourth text";
}

var myObj = {
    first: "First text",
    second: "Second text",
    third: "Third text"
};

myFunction(myObj); 

console.log(myObj.fourth);
```

As you already have mentione, you could bind the object to the function, which generates a new function, which is to called for the result

```js
function myFunction() {
    console.log(this.first);
    this.fourth = "Fourth text";
}

var myObj = {
    first: "First text",
    second: "Second text",
    third: "Third text"
};

myFunction.bind(myObj)();

console.log(myObj.fourth);
```

Comment: Thanks @nina, I wanted to use `this`, but I the function didn't know with object I was referring to, so a `call`, `apply` or `bind` will do that! :)

Answer (score 0):

Using `myObj` as `this` of a  function

```js
var myObj = {
    first: "First text",
    second: "Second text",
    third: "Third text"
};

//use myObj as this of function
function myFunction(){
    console.log(this.first); // "First text"
    this.fourth = "Fourth text";
}
myFunction.call(myObj); 
console.log(myObj.fourth); // "Fourth text"
```

Using `myObj` inside a function

```js
var myObj = {
    first: "First text",
    second: "Second text",
    third: "Third text"
};

//use myObj inside a function
function myFunction(myObj){
    console.log(myObj.first); // "First text"
    myObj.fourth = "Fourth text";
}
myFunction(myObj); 
console.log(myObj.fourth); // "Fourth text"
```

Comment: function myFunction ( myObj ) {
    console.log(myObj.first); // print actual data
    myObj.fourth = "Fourth text"; // assignment
}
    
myFunction(myObj);  // call and do actions inside a function
console.log(myObj.fourth); //  "Fourth text"

Comment: I understand… But if I run your solutions in Google Chromes console, I get, for the first one, `[object Object] undefined` and `undefined`, and for the second  `undefined undefined` and  `undefined`. ??

Comment: last undefined in both cases it is result of code. if you will run in google console `5` - you will see `5`. if you will run console `console.log (5)` you will see `5` `undefined` because console.log did not return anything

Comment: I run my code in console of google chrome, chromium and firefox console and got expected results. are you sure that you run it as is without any changes?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the usage of "this" within your function.
(More about this in JavaScript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this )

Your function is not part of your object. I see you already gave your object as parameter, but you never use it. In place of "this", you have to use your parameter.

```
var myObj = {
    first: "First text",
  second: "Second text",
  third: "Third text"
}


  function myFunction(myObj){
    console.log(myObj.first);
    myObj.fourth = "Fourth text";
  }


myFunction(myObj);
console.log(myObj.fourth);
```

If you want to use "this" then you can do it so:

```
var myObj = {
    first: "First text",
  second: "Second text",
  third: "Third text",
  myFunction: function(){
    console.log(this.first);
    this.fourth = "Fourth text";
  }
}

myObj.myFunction();
console.log(myObj.fourth);
```

Comment: I understand, if I want to use the this there are two options: the function has to be inside the object, or I should use call, apply or bind to relate the function with the object :)